# ANTLR proper ordering of grammar rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write a grammar that will recognize `<<word>>` as a special token but treat `<word>` as just a regular literal.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar test;

doc: item+ ;
item: func | atom ;

func: '<<' WORD '>>' ;
atom: PUNCT+            #punctAtom
    | NEWLINE+          #newlineAtom
    | WORD              #wordAtom
    ;

WS : [ \t] -> skip ;
NEWLINE : [\n\r]+ ;
PUNCT : [.,?!]+ ;
WORD : CHAR+ ;

fragment CHAR : (LETTER | DIGIT | SYMB | PUNCT) ;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
fragment SYMB : ~[a-zA-Z0-9.,?! |{}\n\r\t] ;
```

So something like `<<word>>` will be matched by two rules, both `func` and `atom`.  I want it to be recognized as a `func`, so I put the `func` rule first.

When I test my grammar with `<word>` it treats it as an `atom`, as expected.  However when I test my grammar and give it `<<word>>` it treats it as an `atom` as well.

Is there something I'm missing?

PS - I have separated `atom` into `PUNCT`, `NEWLINE`, and `WORD` and given them labels `#punctAtom`, `#newlineAtom`, and `#wordAtom` because I want to treat each of those differently when I traverse the parse tree.  Also, a `WORD` can contain `PUNCT` because, for instance, someone can write "Hello," and I want to treat that as a single word (for simplicity later on).

PPS - One thing I've tried is I've included `<` and `>` in the last rule, which is a list of symbols that I'm "disallowing" to exist inside a `WORD`.  This solves one problem, in that `<<word>>` is now recognized as a `func`, but it creates a new problem because `<word>` is no longer accepted as an `atom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer tries to match as much characters as possible, so both `<<WORD>>` and `<WORD>` are matched by the lexer rul `WORD`. Therefor, there in these cases the tokens `<<` and `>>` (or `<` and `>` for that matter) will not be created.

You can see what tokens are being created by running these lines of code:

```java
Lexer lexer = new testLexer(CharStreams.fromString("<word> <<word>>"));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
tokens.fill();

for (Token t : tokens.getTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%-20s %s\n", testLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()), t.getText());
}
```

which will print:

```
WORD                 <word>
WORD                 <<word>>
EOF                  <EOF>
```

What you could do is something like this:

```antlr
func
 : '<<' WORD '>>' 
 ;

atom
 : PUNCT+   #punctAtom
 | NEWLINE+ #newlineAtom
 | word     #wordAtom
 ;

word
 : WORD
 | '<' WORD '>'
 ;

...

fragment SYMB : ~[<>a-zA-Z0-9.,?! |{}\n\r\t] ;
```

Of course, something like `foo<bar` will not become a single `WORD`, which it previously would.